# Sphinx problem. Filter

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a problem with Sphinx. I have configuration like this:

```
sql_query               = \
        SELECT id, product_title, product_inf, product_code, ptype_name, title, cat, value, car \
        FROM Catalog_View;
sql_attr_uint           = car
sql_attr_uint           = cat
```

Catalog_View is a view which collect data from several tables. It works good and haven't got any problem. I created index with this configuration:

```
index src1
{
    source          = src1
    path            = /var/data/src1
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = stem_en, stem_ru
    min_word_len        = 3
    charset_type        = sbcs
    min_prefix_len  = 0
    min_infix_len       = 3
    enable_star     = 1
}
```

And indexer done his job perfect. But when I'm looking for empty query (like this '') and setup two filters

```
$cl->SetFilter('cat',array(9));
$cl->SetFilter('car',array(2));
```

I loose a lot of matches. For example when I use SQL-query to Catalog_View I have 76 rows, and the same in Sphinx gives me only 11 rows. I can't figure out what am i doing wrong. Everything seems fine except filter.
Actually I have the same problem with filters when I'm looking for non-empty query.

Comment: In your query are you using AND or OR to select those two columns?

Comment: i don't get what are you talking about... my query is an empty string ('') or some words (like 'car sell')

Comment: You said that you did an SQL query and got more results. My question is did you use AND or OR on the cat and car columns?  Sphinx filters are AND'd together, but you can do an or through the query itself.

Comment: i got it. No, i used something like that SELECT * FROM  `Catalog_View` WHERE cat =9 AND car =2

Comment: Please give some stats: How many documents in the index? How many hits do you get with `search -f cat 9` and `search -f car 2` respectively? What is your `max_matches` setting?

Comment: 25000 docs in the index. 1536 - for car 2; 519 - for cat 9;

Comment: in the interception of 1536 and 519 i need to have 76, but it's only 11.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps you're running out of buffers on the first filter leaving only 11 documents matching the second filter. But it's not that. Short of reading the searchd source code, my best suggestion is try a different version. It could be a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: And have you asked on the Sphinx Forum?

Comment: Greetings Anton, I think you should increase your max_matches as I think it might stop searching for relevant records once it has processed 10000 records

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this one too. My solution was making document IDs unique. If you have duplicated document IDs the possible result can be the same. I suppose Sphinx would take only first unique document thrashing all duplicated data.